# PyObjC Not Working

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc

I've installed PyObjC on my Mac, but I can't get it to work at all. Even trying to import the AddressBook class just fails immediately.

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import AddressBook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "AddressBook.py", line 17, in <module>
    ('Last Name',  AddressBook.kABLastNameProperty),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'kABLastNameProperty'
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a conflicting file named `AddressBook.py` in your working directory.  Rename or remove it or change to another directory.